# Data grid selected row item issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using data grid for my application. When selecting a row, only a part is highlighted. 
for example, If I use 2 columns, only those two are selected, rest of the empty space in that row is not highlighted.

Please advice me to solve this issue.

Thanks
SN

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your columns extend the width of the control:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Width="*" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

If you don't define a width for a DataGrid column it will have a default `Width="Auto"`. Set one column to `Width="*"` in order to get that column to fill up available space. Then when you select it the selection will stretch the width of the bounds.

Alternately define a dummy 3rd column to fill the remaining space:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the operation in required field you want to select / edit.